# Error ReportViewer 14.0.0.0 Window.$RSjQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms, reportviewer

Ao clicar no botão para expandir grupos no reportview, ele fica carregando eternamente e dá erro na linha abaixo:

```
// error Uncaught TypeError: window.$RSjQuery is not a function

if ($) {
     window.$RSjQuery(window).on("resize", function () {
         self.ResizeToolbarIcons();
     });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está ocorrendo porque o *ReportViewer* depende do *$RSjQuery* no momento de exibir a `ToolBar`.

Adicione a seguinte linha de código no evento Page_Load ou Pre_Render

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Me.Page.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlForm).First().Controls.Add(New ReportViewer With {.ID = "rdlcRSQuery", .Width = 0, .Height = 0)
    End If
```

Isso fará com que os Scripts que o *ReportViewer* depende estejam registrados na Página no momento de sua exibição.

Lembre de chamar

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
```

E adicione o seguinte *CSS*

```
<style type="text/css">
    #rdlcRSQuery_ReportViewer { display:none;}
</style>
```